# Windows Server 2012 RD Licensing Issuing Multiple Temp Licenses Per Machine

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, rds, licensing

I have just setup a Windows Server 2012 RDS environment with Per Device CALs.  Looking at RD Licensing Manager it is handing out multiple temp CALS per machine and multiple permanent CALS per machine.  At this rate I will run out of licenses very shortly.

I understand that it would issue a temp license until the second logon, but why would it issue multiple licenses to the same machine?
How can I get a better breakdown of the differences in the issued CALS than RD Licensing Manager?
Any PowerShell commands to find out more information?

Answer (score 1):

The issue happen if the local license store on the PC got erased. (or on cloned PC) (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSLicensing - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187614), the server will issue a new's one.

The 90 days cleaning period will erase those old entry by itselft, but can restrict you in the short term if your license pool is short.

Comment: It's happening on multiple machines sitting in front of me that have not been erased.  Clarify on cloned.  All of our machines are cloned, but sysprepped and cloned the right way.

Comment: Check the registry key I give to be sure no GPO or policy prevent a write there.

Comment: Administrators and System have Full Control - Allow to that key.